# pushViewController only sometimes

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, pushviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

I have a button that I have added to my navigation bar programatically. When I pressed this button, sometimes I want it to `[self.navigationBar popViewControlleranimated:YES]` and sometimes I want it `[self.navigationBar pushViewcontrollerAnimated:YES]` depending on some variables. I can get the `popViewController` part to work, but I am unsure how to do the `pushViewController` part. Mainly, where do I instantiate this viewController? As I understand it, it has to be part of the navigation controller already. But if I made this view in my story board, what do I connect it to to make it part of the navigation controller since my button is inserted programatically? Also, even if my button was not inserted programatically, and I instead added it via the story board, how would the case work when I want to `popViewController` upon pressing the button? If I link the `pushViewController` to this button, woudln't it try to push this view controller when I actually want to pop it? I suppose I could do and unanimated pop followed by an animated one, which might work.

Comment: instead I'd suggest you to write format question properly....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply connect the two nibs in your storyboard with a push segue( from the class of the one to the whole other):
[image]
 and set it's identifier "something"
[image]
, then in your code replace push view controller with:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"something" sender:self];
```